# Cannot get Azure Active Directory Group from my logic app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

Trying to access azure active directory group information but experienced below error.

[image]

Tried many ways but cannot find out the exact reason.

**Config Information:**

I am provided my azure ad `group Id` , and connected with my email `myemail@outlook.com`

Comment: Could you share your request config?

Comment: Take a look. This could help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have configured your `azure active directory` logic app connector with your personal Microsoft Account. As per my understanding you couldn't achieve it with `myemail@outlook.com` you have login with `YourOrgEmail@YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com` email. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Your Case:**

I have successfully reproduce your problem and configure with my Organizational email and got success.  See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Permission:**

I have also noticed that permission also could be the issue. In that case you might encounter `insufficient privilege: 401`  error. So you need at least following permission:

Permission Type: `Application`

Permission Name: `Group.Read.All`

See the screen shot below:

[image]

For more details you could take look this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)